# Move QDialog after second resizeEvent in PyQt

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

## Introduction and short problem description

The example contains resizing a `QScrollArea` and moving a `QDialog` the the screens centere. This two things work well in isolation. But combining them is the problem I can not solve.

While creating the dialog I want to center it to the screen but before that the dialog need "time" to dynamically readjust its (content) size. Technically this are two `resizeEvents()` I need to wait before centering the `QDialog`.

## Detailed description of the problem

I want to the `QDialog` be centered on screen when it is created. It don't need to stick there. After creation the user is free to place it elsewhere.

I do resize the width of the `QScrollArea` to make it fit to its content and prevent the need for horizontal scrolling. Only the (usual) vertical scrollbar should appear.
Keep in mind that resizing the `QScrollArea` also resize the whole `QDialog`. The needed width is calculated based on the child widgets in that scroll area. Before calculation they need to be shown. That is why I do it in `showEvent()` handler. Maybe there is a better solution for this aspect?

While building the `QDialog` two resize events happen. The first happens when the dialog is drawn the first time (the `show()` or `exec()` call). The second happens when I modify the width of the `QScrollArea` which also affects the width of the `QDialog`.

Where and how should I call the `QDialog.move()`?

Because of my explanation I'm able to use `showEvent()` handler for this. It has no effect because the dialog is not yet resized by its `QScrollArea` child. The center of the `QDialog` can't be calculated at this point in the programm flow because its size is not yet finished.

It works when using `resizeEvent()`. But the shortcomming is that centering the `QDialog` do happen every time even when the user just resize the window via its mouse.

## Workarounds

I have two workarounds in mind that might work but I don't like them because they are not elegant not real solutions.

1. Use a flag or counter in `resizeEvent()` if and how often the `_center_to_screen()` was called to prevent multiple calls to it.
2. Use a single shot `QTime()` guessing some milliseconds and call `_center_to_screen()` really only once.

Thank you so much for reading so far.

## Minimal working example

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *


class CenteredDialog(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        # Scroll area with language widget
        scroll = QScrollArea(self)
        scroll.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAsNeeded)
        scroll.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        scroll.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Expanding, QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        scroll.setWidget(self._widget())
        self._scroll = scroll

        # Button "Apply"
        button = QDialogButtonBox(QDialogButtonBox.Apply)
        button.clicked.connect(self.accept)

        # Dialog layout
        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(scroll)
        layout.addWidget(button)

    def _widget(self):
        """Widget with 4 x 25 grid layouted labels"""
        grid = QGridLayout()
        wdg = QWidget(self)
        wdg.setLayout(grid)

        for col in range(1, 5):
            for row in range(1, 26):
                grid.addWidget(
                    QLabel(f'{col} x {row} | Lorem ipsum dolor sit', self),
                    row,
                    col)

        return wdg

    def showEvent(self, e):
        print('Event: show')
        super().showEvent(e)

        # Width of the scroll area is expanded to fit its content.
        widget_width =  self._scroll.widget().sizeHint().width()
        scrollbar_width = self._scroll.verticalScrollBar().sizeHint().width()

        # This cause resizeEvent
        self._scroll.setMinimumWidth(widget_width + scrollbar_width)

        # This don't work here.
        # self._center_to_screen()

    def resizeEvent(self, e):
        print('Event: resize')

        # Works somehow but Is called multiple times
        self._center_to_screen()

    def _center_to_screen(self):
        """Move the dialog to the screens center.
        Credits: https://pythonprogramminglanguage.com/pyqt5-center-window
        """
        geo = QApplication.primaryScreen().availableGeometry()
        rec = self.frameGeometry()
        rec.moveCenter(geo.center())
        self.move(rec.topLeft())


class Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

    def showEvent(self, e):
        dlg = CenteredDialog()
        dlg.exec()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = Window()
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Comment: The problem is that you can never rely on the `showEvent()` if you need complex resizing, as at that point it may be too late *and* further resizing might still happen due to the window manager. You should consider reimplementing `minimumSizeHint()` on the scroll area instead.

Comment: Why not move the call ```scroll.setMinimumWidth()``` into the ```__init__()``` and move the call ```self._center_to_screen()``` into the ```showEvent()```?